# Striving towards a more precise, truthful, and accurate understanding of why gimbal lock happens.

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, rotations, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

Please, somebody explain why gimbal lock happens properly. Not a single correct solution out  there, people always seem to gloss over the important details and if you dig into the common explanations, they all fall to pieces under closer examination.

The common explanation that is given goes something like this...

A plane pitches upwards 90 degrees, now its forward axis "collapses into" its up axis,
and suddenly, yaw looks like roll, and it "loses a degree of freedom, blah blah blah."

It's abhorrent that this is the commonly accepted explanation, here's why that is wrong... the controls of the plane are LOCAL to its perspective, so it doesn't matter WHICH way the plane is currently oriented, pitch will always pitch, yaw will always yaw, roll will always roll, and the pilot will be none the wiser, right?

Alternatively, you can think of the world frame and local aircraft frame as two different data sets, and one does not "overwrite the other" ( same in games, you have the world coordinate system and the player local coordinate system, and its not like you discard one in favor of the other; you can get the player world up or local up at any time, and use it to apply the data you need, and yet people always as the copout explanation, "just use squats, don't use Euler angles..." ).

in the example where the plane is now looking up at the sky after it pitched 90 degrees, yes, yawing and rolling at that point will now have different meanings WITH RESPECT to the world coordinate system!

1. a plane that is pitched up 90 degrees, looking up at the sky, who thinks it is rolling locally, will look like it's YAWing from an outside observer who has the world frame of reference.
2. a plane that is pitched up 90 degrees, looking up at the sky, who thinks it is YAWING locally, will look like it's ROLLING from that same outside observer who has the world frame of reference.

note that (1) and (2) are STILL DISTINCT ROTATIONS, they DID NOT collapse into the same behavior in any way, shape, or form, as is commonly claimed in gimbal lock!

I obviously know that gimbal lock happens, I BELIEVE it happens, and have seen it plenty of times. I know that the "cop out" solution is just use quaternions, which are obviously better, however, this does NOT address the problem - why does it actually happen? Can somebody please explain how axes are "collapsing into each other?"

*Please do not post a gif of a toy plane rotating within 3 nested gimbals - yes, that is sufficient to prove that gimbals can align... AND???

...its not like they physically get "locked" after that! To wash your hands of the issue and say, "welp that explains it" is intellectually dishonest and lazy, please don't do that. Also, gimbals are an extremely bad and unintuitive way of grokking rotations, please use forward, up, and right axes ( or whatever coordinate conventions u prefer ).

( and one more thing, it's my understanding that Euler rotations are intrinsic, each defined with respect to the latest state of the rotational frame axes, and this "accumulation" effect seems to have something to do with it and maybe that's the missing link here, but I guess my math is just too damn weak to see it, can somebody please help! Thank you. )

Comment: This might be better on Aviation SE. My own understanding is that gimbal lock would relate to the instruments in an aircraft rather than to the aircraft itself. The wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock discussed the gimbal lock which occurred on Apollo 11.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Updated the diagram to try and make it easier to visualise.

This is not a mathematical answer. It is just demonstrating that your claim that "its not like they physically get "locked" after that" is not correct.

Take a look at my very crudely drawn set of nested gimbals:

[image]

The rectangular object in the middle represents the aircraft's gyroscope instruments mounted on gimbals. The red gimbal is physically locked to the aircraft by the red blocks but the red gimbal can rotate relative to the red blocks. It is clear the rectangle can yaw around the vertical axis because the blue and red gimbals are free to rotate about the vertical axis. The rectangle can also roll around the tail to the nose axis, because the green gimbal is free to rotate around that axis. However it is not possible to pitch the rectangle around the wing tip to wing tip axis (rotate it in the plane of the screen) because there is no gimbal axis perpendicular to the screen. The rectangular instrument is literally physically locked relative to the red gimbal as far as pitching is concerned. (Under normal circumstance the green gimbal would be at 90 degrees to the red gimbal and there would be no gimbal lock.)

If an aircraft has gyroscope instruments, the gyroscopes are supposed to stay in a fixed orientation relative to the universe, no matter how the aircraft manoeuvres and provide a fixed reference to calculate the orientation of the aircraft, (which is useful when there is zero visibility such as when flying in cloud). If the gimbals are aligned as in the diagram and the aircraft pitches, the gyroscope will be physically forced to pitch with the aircraft (and due to gyroscopic torque reaction it will precess around another axis also) and the gyroscope will no longer be providing a reliable fixed reference to calculate the aircraft's orientation. If due to gimbal lock, the gyroscopic instrument is forced to pitch with the aircraft, the instruments could think the aircraft is level when in fact the aircraft is nose down and heading for the ground, which in foggy conditions, *is not a good thing*.

Comment: Thanks for that very clear drawing of gimbals, However I think this might be a little off. Gimbal lock says that only at certain angles (pitch 90 in a yaw, pitch roll sequence), two rotations become one. But your gimbal device CAN NEVER PITCH to begin with. Its just not built w a pitch axis... Yaw pitch roll gimbal lock situation CAN pitch, but only locks when pitch value is set to 90. u could say, "well the airplane to which the gimbal thingy is attached could pitch" but that would be a a different sequence - pitch yaw roll... Gimbal lock happens only bc intrinsic, ie, sequence matters

Comment: I did not make it clear, but the black vertical axis of the rectangle has a bearing where it connects to the blue rectangle so it is free to rotate. Under normal conditions the gimbals would initially be at right angles to each other and then the rectangle is free to pitch, because the blue gimbal can rotate relative to the green gimbal. The gimbals move during acrobatics and if they happen to align with each other then physical gimbal lock occurs as described.

Comment: Sorry I'm shaky on some of these terms, what is bearing? To be clear, can the object nested inside the gimbals pitch under normal circumstances, yes or no?

Comment: Also confused by there being an airplane inside these gimbals, but this whole contraption is also attached to a real airplane, is that the case? Why would there be a toy plane inside of a nested gimbal array on a plane? What's the analogy? I always assumed the popular gif w a toy plane inside of gimbals is symbolizing an object in world space so that means the gimbals would be "attached" to the world frame, maybe a desk, which doesn't move. Is the attachment of the gimbals to some other frame that also moves, the issue? Really confused now lol

Comment: Sorry. I should have made it clear I meant a ball bearing (not an aircraft heading). I will edit accordingly. Just to be clear. Yes the object in the centre can pitch nose up or nose down under normal circumstances (when the gimbals are not aligned with each other).

Comment: @Dude The "airplane" inside the gimbals is symbolic and just indicates how the real aircraft is initially aligned with the instrument in the centre. Its a bit like the display panel inside a cockpit often have 'toy' aircraft icons to display orientation.

Comment: If it helps consider a magnetic compass. It will not work when it is vertical. For the compass to operate reliably it must be mounted inside gimbals that keep the compass horizontal no matter what the orientation of the aircraft is. In reality, gyroscopes and accelerometers are mounted in the rectangle in the centre, in such a way that they remain in a constant orientation relative to world coordinates.

Comment: @Dude Updated the diagram and some of the text to try and address your comments.

Comment: So keeping them oriented relative to world space is essentially "cheating," in the sense that the compass is now subject to extrinsic instead of intrinsic rotations right? Euler angles, as a sequence of Intrinsic rotations, makes gimbal lock unavoidable when the second angle in the sequence (in this case pitch) == 90. So the free floating gimbals exempt it from this nested/intrinsic process such that every rotation applies to the compass is relative to the unchanging world frame, did I get that right?